# Passing data to .Net MVC controller method as parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just wonder when we pass data to controller method as parameters, why we need to use exactly the same name, any underlying reason?

For example, the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            // Get Faculty PartialView
            url: "/Home/FacultiesToPVDemo",
            type: 'Get',
            data: { courseName: selectedCourseName },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#facultyDetailTable").empty().append(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("something seems wrong");
            }
        });
```

will invoke the following method in the controller:

```
 public ActionResult FacultiesToPVDemo(string courseName)
    {
        IEnumerable<Course> allCourses = _repository.GetCourses();
        var selectedCourseId = (from c in allCourses where c.CourseName == courseName select c.CourseId).FirstOrDefault();

        IEnumerable<Faculty> allFaculties = _repository.GetFaculties();
        var facultiesForCourse = allFaculties.Where(f => f.AllotedCourses.Any(c => c.CourseId == selectedCourseId)).ToList();

        return PartialView("FacultyPV", facultiesForCourse);
    }
```

In the ajax if I use a different data property name other than "courseName", it wouldn't work, even if there is only one parameter to match. why is that?

Comment: it's the model binding that looks to match the parameter names...you could still get the value from the Request

Comment: alternatively, you could write a custom ModelBinder that evaluates the Request object to make the call work :)

Comment: @Icepickle: Oh don't suggest *that*. I know you're trying to be funny, but someone's liable to go off and do something that silly. If you think a custom model binder is the answer, most likely you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: @dotjoe how the parameter is related to model? I think it just serves as a "parameter" for other data to fill in

Answer (score 1):

In exactly the same way that you cannot declare a method as:

```
public void Test(string test = null)
```

.. and expect this to work:

```
obj.Test(notTest: null)
```

If you're not passing your data over with the correct name, it won't bind. Just think of it in the same way, you are calling a method, albeit abstracted by ASP.NET / IIS through a routed HTTP request.

This allows you to have actions that have the same name, but different parameters should you need to accept them and is a benefit rather than a burden.

We may be able to help explain further or suggest alternatives if you give us a scenario where you would like things to be named differently. Things such as custom model binders, action filters (or anything overly complex) or accessing the form values directly (as a keyed array) are always an option depending on your *actual* requirements.

Comment: Ok so what I get is the naming matching is required for the binding to work . It was just defined so, but to me "courseName" is just a parameter in that function to find data in models

Comment: Well, in a logical mind - `courseName` is a course name. If you want to accept something else, add an overload (with a default value, `null`?) or a different method entirely that deals with your separate parameter. The appropriate method will be called depending on what parameters you actually pass over.

Comment: Okay, I mean sometimes as humans we may spell a different way, like "coursename" then it wouldn't match-)

Comment: It's static and defined in your javascript code, I don't see why this matters.

Comment: Never mind, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The [MVC ModelBinder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405(v=VS.90).aspx) needs the names to match in order for it to know how to relate the incoming request data to the correct parameters.

- [6 Tips for ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. What I get is that is just how it works. If there are more than one parameter and we use different names, the ModelBinder would be rather confused, right -: